# AngularJS directive: Reference local variables from external HTML file used in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I hope I phrased my question correctly, I haven't been able to find anything else on this.
Say I have a AngularJS directive, something like this:

```
angular.module( 'example', [] ).directive(
        'exampleDirective', ['$compile', '$http',
        function($compile, $http) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                    var listOfItems = attrs.listOfItems;
                    var foo = attrs.foo;
                    var template =
                        '<ul>' +
                            '<li ng-repeat="item in ' + listOfItems + '">'+
                                '<i ng-click="clicked(item)">'+
                                    '{{item.' + foo + '}}'+
                                '</i>'+
                             '</li>'+
                         '</ul>';

                    element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
                }
             };
          }]);
```

listOfItems being an array with objects like `[{'Name': 'this'}, {'Name': 'that'}]` and foo then being `Name`.

And now I want to place the template in it's own html file and load it with an http call. 
How would the template look in the html file? Since I wont be able to access the local variable in the file I'm not sure what needs to be changed. Any help or comments would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does your template-compile even work? I expect `'item in ' + arrayObject` to result in something like `'item in [object Object],[object Object]'` .. as in a literal string

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure, I just used that as an example. The actual directive I'm using is based on the one in [Angular Treeview](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your external template will have access to your scope variables.

updated directive:

```
angular.module( 'example', [] ).directive(
  'exampleDirective', ['$compile', '$http',
    function($compile, $http) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',

        // ... 

        templateUrl: 'my_template.html',

        // ...
      };
    }
  ]
);
```

my_template.html:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in ' + listOfItems + '">
    <i ng-click="clicked(item)">
      {{item.' + foo + '}}
    </i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So just to clarify, I would put the variables in scope, as in: `var listOfItems = attrs.listOfItems` would become `scope.listOfItems = attrs.listOfItems`

Comment: **IF** you wanted the `listOfItems` to be a reference, you would either need to use `$parse`, or define it in `scope` attribute of directive definition. otherwise it will be a plain string

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve that with `compile` function of the directive, as shown in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TNkrtweqavG5eiXAySZ8?p=preview)

```
directive('exampleDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',

    templateUrl: 'template.html',

    compile: function (element, attrs) {          
      var template = element.html()
                      .replace('#__LIST__#', attrs.listOfItems)
                      .replace('#__FOO__#', attrs.foo);

      element.html(template);

      return function link(scope, element, attrs) {}
    }
   };
});
```

where the `template.html` looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in #__LIST__#">
    <i ng-click="clicked(item)">{{ item.#__FOO__# }}</i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

please let me know if that's what you're after

Comment: ofc. you could use a normal template and just create a new scope with the `listOfItems` and `foo`

Comment: Yes, tomas, thats a pretty cool solution, but putting the variables in scope was easier and seems to work.

Comment: what it also allows you to do is to pass a more "sophisticated" `foo`, like `some.deeper.reference|with:filter`

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `$http.get` to get hold of the html in the link function

or you could add

```
return {
     restrict: 'A',
     templateUrl: 'myhtml.html'
```

the html in myhtml could be:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ' + listOfItems + '">
        <i ng-click="clicked(item)">{{item.' + foo + '}}>
        </i>
    </li>
 </ul>
```